# My terminal crashes and gives me this message when I try to update my server

Tags: javascript, express, terminal, ejs, nodemon

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:77:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49

Node.js v20.10.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I was trying to update my local server for a todo project I'm doing

Comment: Post the code you run...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.